# SQL query : Select record where 3 values are in 3 columns

Tags: sql

I have an input 1, 2 and 3.

How to select a record where these values are in a row ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 IN (1, 2, 3) 
  AND col2 IN (1, 2, 3) 
  AND col3 in (1, 2, 3)
```

If speed is needed, is it necessary also to index col1-col3 ?

Comment: can you share you sample db

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Also add sample data and desired result

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR not and .. if you need al least a single column match

```
  SELECT * 
  from table
  WHERE col1 in (1,2,3) 
  OR col2 in (1,2,3) 
  OR col3 in (1,2,3) ;
```

You query should work you have one of the value 1,2,3  in all the columns

Answer (score 0):

Tag the DBMS you are using in your question.

With that said, assuming you want to get those rows which have (1, 2, 3) in any order of columns col1, col2, col3 i.e.

```
1 2 3
2 1 3
2 3 1
. . .
```

In Oracle, MySQL and Postgresql, you can do this:

```
select *
from t
where (1, 2, 3) in (
    (col1, col2, col3),
    (col1, col3, col2), 
    (col2, col1, col3), 
    (col2, col3, col1), 
    (col3, col1, col2), 
    (col3, col2, col1)
);
```

Comment: yes , thats it. thanks. I tested in and it works. I will follow up this with new question and real data application.

Answer (score 0):

@Gurv has a reasonable solution, but you actually want the inverse.  Assuming your database supports this tuple notation, you can do:

```
select *
from t
where (col1, col2, col3) in ( (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1) );
```

The advantage of this approach is that the database can use an index on `(col1, col2, col3)`.

In other databases, you can use the same index and either `or` or `union all`:

```
where (col1 = 1 and col2 = 2 and col3 = 3) or
      (col1 = 1 and col2 = 3 and col3 = 2) or
      . . .
```

The optimizer should be smart enough to use the index in this case.  If it is not, you can further encourage it with `union`/`union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (col1 = 1 and col2 = 2 and col3 = 3)
union all
select t.*
from t
where (col1 = 1 and col2 = 3 and col3 = 2) 
union all
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach which avoids the slow "where in"
(but works obviously only on numeric fields)

```
select * from t where
max(col1, col2, col3) = max(1,2,3)
and 
min(col1, col2, col3) = min(1,2,3)
and
col1+col2+col3 - max(col1, col2, col3)- min(col1, col2, col3)
= 1+2+3 - max(1, 2, 3) - min(1, 2, 3)
```